# Cómo hacer un filtro por checkbox en javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html5, json, bootstrap

estoy intentando hacer un filtro por checkbox para que me filtre por productos, pero no sé muy bien como debería hacerlo, ya que recién empiezo a programar en este lenguaje.
Tengo un json con los productos:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Intel Core i5 11400",
    "price": 28190,
    "imageUrl": "../images/productos/procesadores/intel-2.jpg",
    "description": "Socket 1200 11th Gen Rocket Lake"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Intel Core i5 11400F",
    "price": 22210,
    "imageUrl": "../images/productos/procesadores/intel-1.jpg",
    "description": "Socket 1200 11th Gen Rocket Lake"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "title": " Intel Core i5 11600KF",
    "price": 33650,
    "imageUrl": "../images/productos/procesadores/intel-2.jpg",
    "description": "Socket 1200 11th Gen Rocket Lake"
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "title": "Intel Core i5 12400",
    "price": 37068,
    "imageUrl": "../images/productos/procesadores/intel-6.jpg",
    "description": "Socket 1700 12th Gen"
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "title": "Intel Core i7 11700K",
    "price": 55009,
    "imageUrl": "../images/productos/procesadores/intel-3.jpg",
    "description": "Socket 1200 11th Gen Rocket Lake"
}
]
```

Luego tengo el fetch en donde lo llamo

```
const fetchData = async() => {
try{
    const res = await fetch("./productos.json");
    const data = await res.json(); 
    // console.log(data); 
    mostrarProductos(data);
    detectarBotones(data);  
} catch(error){
    console.log(error);
 }
}
```

En el html tengo un ul en donde tengo los filtros que quiero hacer, para que los productos aparezcan y desaparezcan en función de si el checkbox está marcado o no:

```
<ul class=" d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row">
            <span class="mx-3">CATEGORIAS:</span>
          <div class="form-check mx-3">
            <input class="form-check-input checkboxes" type="checkbox" id="procesadores" >
            <label class="form-check-label" for="procesadores">
              Procesadores
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check mx-3">
            <input class="form-check-input checkboxes" type="checkbox" id="motherboards">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="motherboards">
              Motherboards
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check mx-3 ">
            <input class="form-check-input " type="checkbox" id="graficas">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="graficas">
              Tarjetas gráficas
            </label>
          </div>
        </ul>
```

Estoy usando bootstrap para darle estilo al proyecto.
Estoy un poco perdido la verdad, si alguien pudiera ayudarme estaría muy agradecido, gracias!

Comment: Antes de nada, si quieres filtrar productos por categoría, no debería de haber un campo en el json que indique dicha categoría?

Comment: Es verdad  es que voy haciendo el proyecto de a poco y se me van ocurriendo cosas que agregarle.. entonces podría agregarle la categoría al json, después recorrerlo y filtrarlo según la categoría, no? como podría hacerlo en código? usando un forEach o algún otro método? 
Gracias por responder

Comment: En la función de mostrar productos, podrías setear dos variables globales con todos los productos una que no se modifique y otra que guarde los filtrados, luego yo agregaría 1 eventListener para cada checkbox(categoría) que llamen a la misma función que dependiendo del valor filtre por esa categoria o no

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: Así como te dice @Suso es la idea, respecto a la pregunta si es con un `forEach`, puedes realizarlo con ese método (tienes que hacer más lógica), pero hay un método para filtrar en los array se llama `filter`.

Comment: Al final lo solucioné con un forEach jaja después voy a intentar reescribirlo con el filter, gracias por su ayuda!